# C# UWP VS2017 ComboBox event error: unable to activate Windows store app

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I tried to create an eventhandler for a combobox in an UWP app that when I change the value to a certain item some controls on the form get hidden. The problem is that when I choose to start without debugging I get an error: unable to activate Windows store app. Now I dont know is this is caused by the code or by something else. When I remove the event from the code the problem is gone and if I only remove the body from the eventhandler the problem remains so I am fairly certain the problem is not in the body.

This is the C# + XAML code:

```
private void RoleComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (roleComboBox.SelectionBoxItem.ToString() == "Coach")
        {
            positionTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            positionComboBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

<ComboBox x:Name="roleComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,84,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" SelectionChanged="RoleComboBox_SelectionChanged">
        <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">-Choose a role-</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Player</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Coach</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Trainer</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

I first thought the problem was somewhere in VS2017 (also tried 2019) and tried a lot of solutions I found on the internet regarding this problem. After trying solutions for 10+ hours (I never thought the problem was in the code as all the problems on the internet descriped it as a problem with the debugger) I tried to comment the last part I coded as the problem occured at that time and wasnt there before that. This solved my problem so I pinpointed the error to the eventhandler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you place `ComboBoxItem` in the `ComboBox`, so the selected item type is `ComboBoxItem`, we need to convert it to ComboBoxItem then get `Content` property like the following.

```
private void RoleComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = roleComboBox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
    var value = item.Content;
    if ((roleComboBox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString() == "Coach")
    {
        positionTextBlock.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
      
    }
}
```

Comment: That made it work. My code didnt gave any compilere error so I couldnt see what was wrong, It just crashed at runtime and gave me the 'unable to activate Windows store app' error. I dont know if the is a bug or not but its hard to tell for me what went wrong.

Same thing happens when I want to make the ComboBox visible again. It just crashes at runtime. The code positionTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; works just fine but when I use positionComboBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; it just crashes.

Comment: You could use try-catch block to catch the error info or set a break point to check which line throw exception. And if above is helpful please consider [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)it.

Comment: I already used breakpoint in the debugger and found the line positionComboBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; is giving the error. Same thing happens if I use the dame code for a Textbox. A Textblock works just fine. Try-catch doesnt give me any info on the cause of the error. Anything else I can do? Also marked your awnser, sorry forgot it before.

Comment: Yep, you could also use `debug.writeline` to print info in the method which line may throw exception.

Comment: Gives me a NullReference. Doesnt really make sense to me for 2 reasons. First the instance of the object doesnt get destroyed, or does collapse destroy it? The TextBlock doesnt give this message although it also an instance of the class TextBlock? Or am I missing something obvious?